# PHP PDO MySQL strings and variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo

Why does this work when using the value direct?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT tablename FROM database WHERE item = :item');
$stmt->execute(array('item ' => "somevalue" ));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

But this one does not work when using a variable?

```
$itemstring = "somevalue"
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT tablename FROM catalogs WHERE item = :item ');
$stmt->execute(array('item ' => $itemstring));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Am I missing something obvious?

This is on WAMP 2.4/MySQL

Only change is that I am using a variable instead of a string?

Comment: This should work fine as is (apart from the missing `;`, hoping that's a copy and paste error). Either clarify what exactly "doesn't work" means, or provide your *actual* code (since this one can't be your actual code, since it should work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a semi-colon at end of first line. This should also be visible in your error log.

**ALWAYS check your error log!**

If you dont get errors, fix this before doing anything else.

```
$itemstring = "somevalue"; // <- missing semi-colon at end
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT tablename FROM catalogs WHERE item = :item ');
$stmt->execute(array('item ' => $itemstring));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I missed it when copying from notepad to the site. i removed the real tables names etc. My code does have this: $itemstring = "somevalue"; at the end. Just do not understand why it does not work?

Comment: Please see the bold part :)

Comment: Apologies should have mention there is no errors in the logs when running these. Even cleared the logs and restarted WAMP. Just the one brings a result and the other does not. But will keep looking. Might be something else.

Comment: Are you sure your error logging is working? Did you try `echo 1/0;` to see if any error shows up anywhere? If you really dont get an error, your code IS working but the select returns no result, probably because your variable contents of $itemstring are not what you think they are!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was: HTML characters in my string! The string returns text but has tags like this: **string1** (bold html tags) where it was supposed to be this: string1

i fix the issue with:

```
$MYFILTERVALUE= preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $_POST['stringtoget']);
```

This sanitizes the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is late but I'm pretty sure the syntax should be like the below. And this can help you understand a bit more about how PDO works.
```

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

```
$itemstring = "somevalue"; 
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare('SELECT tablename FROM catalogs WHERE item = :item ');
$stmt->execute(array(':item' => $itemstring));<-- Colon in the identifier
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Or

```
$itemstring = "somevalue";
$query="SELECT tablename FROM catalogs WHERE item = :item";
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($query);
$params = array(':item' => $itemstring);<-- Colon in the identifier, setting parameters.
$stmt->execute($params);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.